# Rails: Validate associated and saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, associations

I'm aware of `validates_associated`, but I'm not sure it does what I need it to do...

I have a model `Photo` which has_one `Attachment` -- I need to make sure the photo has an associated, valid, saved attachment before the photo itself saves.

Does validates_associated cover all of that, or is there a different/better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`validates_presence_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of) in addition to `validates_associated`. As noted in the API:

> [`validates_associated`] will not fail if the association hasn’t been assigned. If you want to ensure that the association is both present and guaranteed to be valid, you also need to use `validates_presence_of`.